# Count if there are more smaller or larger number in a result made of multiple Xs?

Tags: calculus, average

Firstly, I am not a math pro or something. So far I was able to use math for my needs, but now I am at my wits' ends. Here is the deal.

These things are known to me:

```
Avg 1,234, High 2,740, Low 548
```

**Q: Can I know if more numbers which made the `Avg` result are below the `Avg` value or above it?**

Now, let me explain what part is known and what is unknown.

- I know the max number and the min nuber all the time.
- The `Avg` value is average of **all numbers**.
- I always know how many numbers are in the game. In this case there are 22 numbers, **but some of them can be 0** so they don't contribute to the `Avg` result.

The important thing is that I **can enter 1 value on my own** to see how `Avg` will change? And I can change my number as many times as I wish.

For example, if I enter `2000`, the `Avg` value will change to `1290`. My entry is 23rd value.

So, is there a way to calculate what I need? Or it's not possible even for the math due to too many unknown variables?

Comment: Why would zero values not contribute to the average? Is the average of $\{0,1\}$ the same as the average of $\{1\}$?

Comment: $\dfrac{1234\times 22 +2000}{23}\approx 1267.3$ not $1290$

Comment: I think the question is perfectly clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot know. For example, take the sets $\{0,1,6,13\}$ and $\{0,3,4,13\}$ . For both, you have 
    Avg $5$, High $13$, Low $0$

However, in the first, you have the same number of values above and below the average, in the second, you have more numbers below the average.